# Android battery draining rate

Tags: android, battery, batterylevel, battery-saver

I'm trying to design an app which changes it's behaviour according to battery draining rate.
That is, there are two states state1 and state2.
it checks for draining rate of each state. 
and switches over to the particular state which drains less battery.

so is it possible to check the draining rate of my app (in particular).
ps: both the states use display and network connections.

if yes how can I get the draining rate?

I've noticed in the Battery options of android setting contains per app battery usage can I access these values?

Answer (score 0):

You have two main states (LOW and OKEY). However, I don't think you can access battery usage statistics par apps.

You can read this : http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

IMO, you can do what you want with that.